# get time for timezone

Tags: sql, postgresql, timezone

I'm hurting my head again this :

On postgresql, I would like to get the local time for a given timezone.

So, at `15:45` GMT, I want `16:45` for `+01:00`, but I can't get the good anwser :

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/8660)

**Query 1**:

```
select current_timestamp at time zone 'GMT' as time_local_gmt
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/8660/0)**:

```
|              time_local_gmt |
|-----------------------------|
| 2018-01-26T15:45:10.871659Z |
```

This is OK.

**Query 2**:

```
select current_timestamp at time zone '+01:00' as time_local_paris
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/8660/1)**:

```
|            time_local_paris |
|-----------------------------|
| 2018-01-26T14:45:10.871659Z |
```

This is totally wrong, seem like it's `-01:00` instead of `+01:00`

---

**Edit :**
See the valid answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/48707297/5546267

Comment: `select current_timestamp at time zone '+2' as plus_two;` results in `2018-01-26T13:45:10.871659Z`

Comment: @Clijsters so it's exactly the opposite of what I want : the local time at `+2` for a GTM of `15:45` is `17:45`, they are 2 hours ahead of GMT...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally found how to !

```
SELECT
    current_timestamp 
        AT TIME ZONE 'GMT' 
        AT TIME ZONE '+01:00' 
            AS time_local_paris_right;
```

The timestamp is UTC without TZ by default, you force it as a GMT one, and then the second `AT` convert it with the right offset to give you the local time for the specified time zone.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/9695)

**PostgreSQL 9.6 Schema Setup**:

**Query 2**:

```
select current_timestamp at time zone 'GMT' as time_local_gmt
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/9695/1)**:

```
|              time_local_gmt |
|-----------------------------|
| 2018-02-09T13:44:56.824107Z |
```

**Query 3**:

```
select current_timestamp at time zone '+01:00' as time_local_paris_wrong
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/9695/2)**:

```
|      time_local_paris_wrong |
|-----------------------------|
| 2018-02-09T12:44:56.824107Z |
```

**Query 4**:

```
select current_timestamp at time zone 'GMT' at time zone '+01:00' as time_local_paris_right
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/9695/3)**:

```
|      time_local_paris_right |
|-----------------------------|
| 2018-02-09T14:44:56.824107Z |
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.

```
select current_timestamp at time zone 'UTC+1';
```

Gave me the following result.

```
2018-01-26T17:00:58.773039Z
```

There is also a list of [timezone names](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/view-pg-timezone-names.html).

Here is an excerpt from the PostgreSQL 9.6 documentation regarding timezone names.

> The view pg_timezone_names provides a list of time zone names that are recognized by SET TIMEZONE, along with their associated abbreviations, UTC offsets, and daylight-savings status.

Basically, the following query will give you the current time in Paris.

```
SELECT current_timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Paris';
```

Good Luck!

Comment: 'UTC+1' don't give me 17 but 15 :/ and I don't have the timezone name, only the timezone offset.

Comment: @Blag - If you have only the offset, then you can't account for when Paris is UTC+2 for CEST, so your conversions will be off by an hour for about half of each year.  Find a way to work with time zone names.  `Europe/Paris` is the correct way to handle this.

Comment: True for the UTC+1/+2... I'll take a look at how to take this into account. I'll go for your answer, even if the first part is still false for me ;)

Answer (score 1):

For completeness (even if @Avi Abrami's answer should be what you're searching for) let's take a look at the [datetime operators in the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#OPERATORS-DATETIME-TABLE).

One can use the `INTERVAL` keyword to add hours to the stored value:

```
SELECT current_timestamp AT TIME ZONE INTERVAL '+02:00' AS plus_two;
```

Which then results in

```
2018-01-26T17:45:10.871659Z
```

(when GMT time is `2018-01-26T15:45:10.871659Z`)

Section [9.9.3 AT_TIME_ZONE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT) mentions my use of `INTERVAL` without any preceeding operator:

> In these expressions, the desired time zone zone can be specified either as a text string (e.g., 'PST') or as an interval (e.g., **INTERVAL '-08:00'**). In the text case, a time zone name can be specified in any of the ways described in Section 8.5.3.

Comment: The interval seem to work, I've found another way with `current_timestamp::timestamp at time zone '+01:00' as time_local_paris` that work too

Comment: I'm not sure if this casts a `timestamptz` to an `timestamp` and postgresql does something different with them https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-TIMEZONES) says:

> Another issue to keep in mind is that in POSIX time zone names, positive offsets are used for locations **west** of Greenwich. Everywhere else, PostgreSQL follows the ISO-8601 convention that positive timezone offsets are **east** of Greenwich.

I guess that is your problem.

Comment: Yes, this is probably the root cause, but I don't understand why `current_timestamp::timestamp at time zone '+01:00' as time_local_paris` work then...

Comment: These are two different functions. The ostensible inebriation is due to conflicting standards.